# Ambiguous question

Tags: ambiguity, logic

I came across a whatsapp message a few years ago about a question framed in a manner that no matter what the person answers they will be considered that thing they want to deny being. Unfortunately, I don't remember the exact question and am hence asking for an example here if someone knows or came across the same. It was something like:

You are not a stupid person?

Here if I answer "yes" it would suggest that I am not stupid and if I answer No then I am stupid. But that question was framed in a way that regardless of whether one said yes or no, it would still imply they are stupid. What question would have that result?

Comment: A similar question would be "Is the answer to this question 'No'?"

Comment: It's an ill-formed question, a form of words using a yes - no question (here, a declarative question) format, but not leading to a sensible 'yes' or 'no' response. A way of dealing with such nuisance 'questions' is usually available (Here, disambiguating with the pragmatically unequivocal  'No, I'm not a stupid person') (the 'no' may be omitted).

Comment: It's a rhetorical question.  An answer is not expected.

Comment: The answer could be "I agree" or "that's right" etc. Where does it say that questions must be answered by 'yes' or 'no' only? At an interview, you'll make it very hard to have a dialogue. And under interrogation you'll be likely to incriminate yourself. So answering some questions with 'yes' or 'no' *does* make you stupid.

Comment: The classic is *When did you stop beating your wife?* By the time you answer that you didn't stop cause you never beat..., all we heard is that you didn't stop. Similarly, *You're immature* doesn't end well with **I'm Not Immature!**

Comment: Ok, I finally found the original message. It was a statement followed by a question: "Stupid people always say 'no'. Are you stupid?".